# ERROR: relation "information_schema.tables" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 11 and I'm getting this error:

`ERROR: relation "information_schema.tables" does not exist`

when I run this command:

`select * from information_schema.tables`

Can anyone explain why is this happening.

Sorry for not giving more details on problem. I thought someone already had same issue.

I'm using Azure Database for PostgreSQL servers (PostgreSQL version 11). Today when I tried to do migrations I got a error above. When I restore database locally error doesn't show (local PostgreSQL server matches version of  Azure PostgreSQL server). I didn't do any updates and nothing is showing in logs on Azure PostgreSQL server.

Thank you.

Comment: In `psql` does `\dnS` show `information_schema`? Are you running the query as a superuser and if not what user?

Comment: There's no issue with the command. Just make sure you are root.

Comment: So I tried to do migration and it throws that error. I thought it's a backend issue but when I tried to run command from database as root I get the same error.

Comment: @bam What do you mean, root? We are talking about the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: That means that something is deeply wrong. Either you are not using PostgreSQL (perhaps this is some lobotomized PostgreSQL fork), or somebody messed with the catalog tables, or you have data corruption.

Comment: I know something is deeply wrong here. I'm just trying to figure out how something like  this could have happened. Probably gonna need to create server form scratch.

Comment: What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: This: `PostgreSQL 11.15, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I was referring to the superuser. root is not appropriate here.

Comment: @bam you do not have to be a superuser to do this, though if you are not what you see may be limited to the objects that the user you are running as privileges on.

Comment: 1) So what happens when you do `\dnS` in `psql`? 2) How did you do the migration? Add information as update to question.

Comment: You still have not defined what `do migrations` means? Nor have you answered what `\dnS` returns? You really need to provide the information asked or this question is going nowhere.